Using zip in conjunction with zipWith in Haskell
I'm currently learning Haskell, and I am stuck with the following conundrum. What is wrong with the following construction?:
zip [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
Result: [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]

zipWith (+) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
Result: [5,7,9]

zipWith (zip) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
          OR
zipWith zip [1,2,3] [4,5,6]

Result: <interactive>:22:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num [()]) arising from a use of ‘it’
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Expected Result: [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]


What am I missing?

zipWith (,) would do that. zip 1 4 does not make sense.

@NaïmFavier please elaborate, I'm new to the language. What is wrong with doing zip [1] [4]?

Nothing, but that's not what I wrote. zipWith zip [1,2,3] [4,5,6] = [zip 1 4, zip 2 5, zip 3 6], but zip works on lists, not numbers.

Ah! that makes sense. So zipWith zip [[1],[2],[3]] [[4],[5],[6]] should work?

however, that gives a different albeit similar looking result: [[(1,4)],[(2,5)],[(3,6)]]

As I said, zipWith (,) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]. (Note that zip can be defined as zipWith (,).)

in short: zip is applied to the elements of the lists, not the entire lists.
zip is not a sensical function to combine two elements that are not lists. Indeed, zip has type zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)] [Hackage]. It thus takes two lists and creates 2-tuples with these lists.
This means that zipWith will work with zip as function if we have a list of lists:
zipWith zip [[1],[2,3]] [[4],[5, 6]]  -- [[(1,4)], [(2, 5), (3, 6)]]

here the outer zipWith thus zips the outer structures, and zip will be called on zip [1] [4] and zip [2, 3] [5, 6] to produce [(1, 4)] and [(2, 5), (3, 6)] respectively.
zip is a shortcut for:
zip = zipWith (,)

indeed, (,) :: a -> b -> (a, b) is a data constructor, and therefore also a function that takes two elements, and produces a 2-tuple of these two elements, so:
zipWith (,) [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6]  -- [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

will zip the two lists together.

So how does No instance for (Num [()]) arising from a use of ‘it’ fit in here? Or is it like the LISP world of incomprehensible error messages?

When GHC sees a numeric literal like 1, it goes searching for a Num instance for the type it's expecting.  If it's expecting Int or Double or something, it all works as intended.  If it's expecting a list, you'll get a weird error message about a missing Num [...] instance.  Here, GHC was expecting 1 to be a list of some unspecified type (which it decided to default to unit AKA ()).  To evaluate 1 :: [()], it went searching for a Num [()] instance, and that's why you get the weird error message.  You can get similar weird error messages with map (*2) 1 or 1+[2].
